# The header repeats every other row when writing to a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

Using Tweepy, I am writing to a csv file with python and the header repeats every other row

```
x=0
x+=1

with open('NAME' + str(x) + '.csv', 'w' , newline='') as f:
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Name").items(5):
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow(['Username', 'location'])
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow([user.screen_name , user.location])
```

Comment: Move the first two lines in your for-loop to before your for-loop, otherwise those headers get written before every line. Delete the third line of your for-loop (no need to recreate the already existing writer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should change to this:

```
x=0
x+=1

with open('NAME' + str(x) + '.csv', 'w' , newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow(['Username', 'location'])
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Name").items(5):
        thewriter.writerow([user.screen_name , user.location])
```

You only need to create `thewriter` object one time, and of course, you only want to create the headers once, not every other row as you saw. Moving things out of the for loop where you are looping through the rows enables that.